# Call to a member function setTopic() on array in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

```
public function updateSubTopicAction(Request $request ,$id) {
     $updatesubtopic = $this->getDoctrine()
             ->getRepository('FeedbackBundle:Subtopics')
             ->findASubtopics($id);
     //print_r($updatesubtopic);die;

     if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
         $update = $request->request->all();
         //print_r($update);die;
         $updatesubtopic->setTopic($update['Topicname']);
         $updatesubtopic->setName($update['subtopicname']);
         $updatesubtopic->setDetails($update['subtopicdetails']);
         //print_r($updatesubtopic);die;
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $em->persist($updatesubtopic);
         $em->flush();
         return new RedirectResponse($this-generateUrl('view_topic'));
     }
     return $this-render(
         'FeedbackBundle:SubTopic:update_sub_topic.html.php',
         array('updatesubtopic'=>$updatesubtopic)
     );
}
```

how can i update data?

Comment: Please, can you show your findASubtopics method. Looks like this method returns array(the method should return Subtopics object).

Comment: There is a example how update object http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object

Comment: User symfony2 forms to avoid such errors.

Comment: Like @AnnaAdamchuk said the query returning array of objects (in this case one), you can use `getSingleResult()` in your repository method to return only one object not wrapped with array.